# RabbitMQ - Trust store lets all the connections through

Tags: java, rabbitmq, whitelist, truststore

I've got an issue with RabbitMQ's Trust Store.
I've installed the plugin as shown on github, the plugin loads indeed, it even responds when I drop in the certificates to the whitelist folder (if I drop a bad cert.pem like private key I get an error response that the certificate isn't a certificate, if I drop a good one i get response like this: trust store: loading certificate 'cert.pem') - and that's great. 
But, this is where the problems begin. the MQTT and AMQP connections i make with my Java client are passed through, even if there are no certificates present in the whitelist folder. If i understand correctly the idea of the whole plugin, they should be only passed through if there are certificates present in the whitelist folder, otherwise they shouldn't be.

Anyone happened to struggle with the same thing?

Tech: RabbitMQ on docker, Java client using bouncycastle library for ssl

// EDIT
Addon: Rabbitmq.config file

```
[
    { rabbit, [
    { loopback_users, [ ] },
    {ssl_handshake_timeout, 100000},
            { tcp_listeners, [ 5672 ] },
            { ssl_listeners, [ 5671 ] },
            { ssl_options, [
                    { cacertfile, "/etc/tls/cacert.pem" },
                    { certfile, "/etc/tls/cert.pem" },
        { keyfile, "/etc/tls/key.pem" },
        { verify, verify_peer },
                    { fail_if_no_peer_cert, true },
        { reuse_sessions, false}
            ] },
            { default_pass, <<"guest">> },
            { default_user, <<"guest">> },
            { default_vhost, <<"/">> },
            { hipe_compile, false }
    ] },
    { rabbitmq_management, [ { listener, [
            { port, 15671 },
            { ssl, true },
            { ssl_opts, [
                    { cacertfile, "/etc/tls/cacert.pem" },
                    { certfile, "/etc/tls/cert.pem" },
                    { fail_if_no_peer_cert, false },
                    { keyfile, "/etc/tls/key.pem" },
                    { verify, verify_peer }
            ] }
    ] } ] },
    { rabbitmq_mqtt, [
            { vhost, <<"/">> },
            { exchange, <<"amq.topic">> },
            { default_user, <<"guest">> },
            { default_pass, <<"guest">> },
            { tcp_listeners, [ 1883 ] },
            { ssl_listeners, [ 8883 ] }
    ] },
    {rabbitmq_trust_store, [
         {directory,        "/etc/whitelist"}, 
         {refresh_interval, {seconds, 30}},
         {log_levels, [{connection, debug}, {channel, debug}, {federation, debug}]}
    ]}
].
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty much guessing based on the limited amount of information provided, but you probably don't have TLS configured to verify the client's certificate. You need to use the `verify_peer` RabbitMQ configuration option. We have comprehensive docs that I suggest that you read - https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html, https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html

Also please note that the certificates that you whitelist are the CA certificate(s) used to sign the client certificates that your applications present, not the client certificates themselves.

Finally, the best way to get help quickly is to provide a set of files that someone can use to run RabbitMQ and a test application to see the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've added a config file in the post. It still passes everything through. I forgot to mention, that the certificates are self-signed.

Comment: Are you certain your code is connecting to port 5671? Have you tried this without using the trust store?

Comment: 5671 is for SSL AMQP, right? I have to use SSL MQTT protocol, therefore i use the 8883 port. I've tried connecting with and without trust store plugin, the results are the same - i can connect without any problems (even if the trust store whitelist folder is empty)

Comment: Have you tried the TLS AMQP port with an AMQP client? I will double-check how to configure TLS for MQTT as I'm surprised it doesn't also have an `ssl_options` section.

Comment: You should use [these instructions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html) to ensure TLS is configured correctly for all TLS-enabled ports. `openssl` is a useful tool here.

Comment: I, actually, did try it with SSL AMQP, it still lets everything through. The TLS is configured properly - if i don't present the certificate, or i do present an invalid one i get connection error from rabbit (handshake_failure) for both AMQP and MQTT.

Comment: "The TLS is configured properly - if i don't present the certificate, or i do present an invalid one i get connection error from rabbit" - this is a new detail that is important. What do you mean by "present an invalid" certificate here? Do you mean invalid as in bad data or invalid as in not signed by your CA? At this point this discussion should go to the mailing list since SO isn't the right place. Ideally, you would provide certificates that reproduce this issue. I suggest you compare your certs with those generated by [this tool](https://github.com/michaelklishin/tls-gen).

Comment: I have verified that `rabbitmq_trust_store` works as expected for MQTT connections. See complete set of certs and details [here](https://github.com/lukebakken/tls-trust-store-55179047).

Comment: What did you have to change in your environment?